# How can I find the names of log files with 'error' on the last line?

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to find the id's of jobs that end in error.

When I use

```
for i in *log
do tail -n 1 $i | grep error
echo $i
done
```

It seems to find error on the last line of each file, even for files that don't have errors on the last line, and returns all of the filenames with

```
STOP fatal_error
out1.log
STOP fatal_error
out2.log
STOP fatal_error
out3.log
....
```

even though

```
grep error out1.log
```

returns nothing

Alternatively, is there an easier way to get a list of the jobs that end in error? I tagged with qsub because I use qsub to submit the jobs

Comment: Please don't strike out your question and repeat the answer. That's not the way this site works.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to it's previous state. There's no need to change it, because everyone can clearly see the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an if statement so that you only echo the filename when the grep succeeds:

```
for i in *.log
do  
    if tail -n 1 $i | grep error > /dev/null 
    then 
        echo $i
    fi  
done
```

Also, redirect the `grep` results to `/dev/null` so it doesn't appear in the output.

Comment: An if statement isn't strictly required. Consider: `for i in *.log ; do tail -n 1 "$i" | grep -q error && echo $i; done`

Answer (score 2):

You want to say

```
do tail -n 1 $i | grep error
```

not

```
do tail -n 1 *.log | grep error
```

Otherwise, you are checking every log file at every iteration and will always get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect.
echo $i will have the listing of the file, not the grep output